# forkしたSphinxをローカルのclone環境でpytestを実行すると「tests/test_ext_imgconverter.py」がFAILする。

Tags: python3, sphinx, imagemagick

#### 現象

forkしたsphinxをローカルのclone環境でpytestを実行すると「tests/test_ext_imgconverter.py」がFAILする。「svgimg.svg」ないというエラー。

メッセージを見てフォルダーを確認すると次の通り

- /tmp/pytest-of-USERNAME/pytest-1/ext-imgconverter/svgimg.svg … あり
- /tmp/pytest-of-USERNAME/pytest-1/ext-imgconverter/_build/doctrees/images/ … なし

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### 原因

ImageMagickがないのが原因。これを追加インストールすることで解決。

#### 解決までの流れ

1. エラー内容+αから `sphinx.ext.imageconverter` のテストだと分かる。
2. 参考情報を特定し、ImageMagickが必要と分かる。

   - https://www.sphinx-doc.org/ja/master/usage/extensions/imgconverter.html
3. これをインストールしてpytestを再実行。passを確認。